# Font not working

Tags: css, fonts

This font works on w3schools website, but not on my webpage and jsfiddle.

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/6L93tuou/6/)

HTML

```
<div>
With CSS3, websites can finally use fonts other than the pre-selected "web-safe" fonts.
</div>
```

CSS

```
@font-face {
   font-family: "Penultimate";
    src: url("http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/17a456c0eb7e6bd88cb1d090126915f7.eot");
    src: url("http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/17a456c0eb7e6bd88cb1d090126915f7.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/17a456c0eb7e6bd88cb1d090126915f7.woff") format("woff"),
    url("http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/17a456c0eb7e6bd88cb1d090126915f7.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/17a456c0eb7e6bd88cb1d090126915f7.svg#Penultimate") format("svg");
}

div {
   font-family: Penultimate;
}
```

Comment: your code is working here (the one on the post, not the jsfiddle).

Comment: It's not working on the jsfiddle because the font isn't being loaded over https, so it's being blocked for safety. Just open the console. If you could share your webpage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSFiddle uses HTTPS, therefore browsers block loading the font for security reasons. You will see errors in the browser console.

[image: Errors in console]

Firefox allows you to temporarily ignore the errors by clicking on the certificate section of the address bar.

[image: working fonts]